# How to add a placeholder item to an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I add a custom text at the end to a listbox without adding it to the apples collection using ItemsSource?

```
e.g.
Listbox:
Listbox Item1-Apple
Listbox Item2-Apple
Listbox Item3-Apple.. Could be more or less Apple the last item should say "ADD NEW..."
Listbox Item4-ADD NEW...
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="lbxFruits" Margin="0,0,70,52">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation = "vertical" Background="Green">
                    <Label>Hello</Label>
                    <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Price, ElementName=lbxFruits}" Width = "14" />

                    <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Name, ElementName=lbxFruits}" />

                </StackPanel >
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="690,404,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
private void RebuildList()
{
    ListBoxItem addItem = new ListBoxItem() { Content = "ADD NEW ..." };
    lbxFruits.ItemsSource = apples;
}

private ObservableCollection<Fruit> apples ;
public ObservableCollection<Fruit> Apples
{
    get
    {
        return this.apples;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != this.apples)
        {
            this.apples = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really want this special item to be part of the ListView, you must manually fix its position. You would insert new items instead of adding them. Also your collection must support this special item. Either define the type of the collection as `object` or create a e.g. NewItem type that extends Fruit or implements a common interface (this interace is the then collection type).

Comment: If you are not interested in showing text, but a blank line, you can use the [`CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.newitemplaceholder?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) feature instead. If you enable this feature, the collection view will automatically ignore this special item when navigating or when adding new items the special item is automatically positioned first/last. It's the feature that the DataGrid uses to allow the user to add new rows.

Comment: @BionicCode I am not allowed to modify the existing property apples, is there a way to use composition or a converter to only use that value in the UI but never exist in the C# code/model?

Comment: @BionicCode Yes I need to show the Text

Comment: *" I am not allowed to modify the existing property apples"* - not sure what this exactly means. You are not allowed to modify the class and class structure or not to change the value of a property? I guess you must use the class hierarchy as it is? If you can't also change the type of the collection to `object` or create a new Fruit type, then you can only rely on convention: a) create a readonly reference to a dedicated Fruit instance. b) use this instance and add it to your collection as the placeholder item.

Comment: c) Identify the placeholder by comparing its equality with the readonly placeholder instance. The placeholder is a common Fruit. But if you can change the collection to `object`, you can use the static `
CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder` as placeholder item.

Comment: Wit, I will post an example that does not require any additional items by using the CollectionView (as already suggested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the placeholder feature of the `CollectionView`: it will handle the positioning of the placeholder item automatically (for example pin it at the end or beginning). When iterating over the collection, this placeholder item won't appear, thus won't pollute your data structure.

The big advantage is that since focusing on the collection view, you don't have to modify existing data models and their related logic.

You enable the placeholder item by setting the `IEditableCollectionView.NewItemPlaceholderPosition` property to either `NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning` or `NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtEnd`. Common collections that implement `IList` (for example `ObservableCollection`) are represented by the `ListCollectionView` which implements `IEditableCollectionView`.
After enabling the placeholder feature, the collection view of the underlying source collection will now contain the static `CollectionView.PlaceholderItem`.

You can then create a dedicated `DataTemplate` for the `CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder` which is of type `object` (the underlying type is defined `internal` and therefore not accessible for client code of the .NET library).

A custom `DataTemplateSelector` will then identify this placeholder item to return the appropriate `DataTemplate`.

The `DataTemplate` for the placeholder item contains a `Button` that allows to add a new item on click (using an `ICommand` or event handler) and to display the placeholder item's text.

**FruitTemplateSelector.cs**

```cs
public class FruitTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  /* Add more template properties in case you have more data types */

  public DataTemplate AppleTemplate { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate PlaceholderTemplate { get; set; }

  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) => item switch
  {
    var dataItem when dataItem == CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder => this.PlaceholderTemplate,
    Apple _ => this.AppleTemplate,
    _ => base.SelectTemplate(item, container),
  };
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> TextItems { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
 
    this.TextItems = new ObservableCollection<string>
    {
      "Item #1",
      "Item #2",
      "Item #3"
    };

    // Get the default collection view of the source collection
    ICollectionView textItemsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.TextItems);

    // Enable the placeholder item 
    // and place it at the end of the collection view
    IEditableCollectionView editableCollectionView = textItemsView as IEditableCollectionView;
    editableCollectionView.NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtEnd;
  }

  private void AddNewItem_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => this.TextItems.Add($"Item #{this.TextItems.Count + 1}";
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TextItems}"
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
      <local:FruitTemplateSelector>
        <local:FruitTemplateSelector.AppleTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </local:FruitTemplateSelector.AppleTemplate>

        <local:FruitTemplateSelector.PlaceholderTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Add New Item..."
                    Click="AddNewItem_OnClick"
                    Background="Orange" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </local:FruitTemplateSelector.PlaceholderTemplate>
      </local:FruitTemplateSelector>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in which this can be achieved.
I would suggest that you define an interface for your `Fruit` and have your `ObservableCollection` contain a list of class instances that implement that interface. Something like:

```
interface IFruit
{
  string Name{get;set;}
  string Price{get;set;}
}

class Apple:IFruit
{
  string Name{get;set;}
  string Price{get;set;}
}

class AddApple:IFruit
{
  string Name{get;set;} = "Add New Apple";
  string Price{get;set;}
}

public ObservableCollection<IFruit> Apples
```

Then you just need to trigger your the code to add a new `Apple` either by reacting to an `OnClick` event and determining whether it has come from an `AddApple` class type or by adding a command to the interface which is implemented within `AddApple` to run the add new apple code and within the `Apple` class to do something else (or nothing at all).

You could in fact add the interface to `Fruit` class as I assume that `Apple` inherits from it.

e.g.,

```
abstract class Fruit : IFruit
{
  public virtual string Name{get;set;}
  public virtual string Price{get;set;}
}

class Apple : Fruit
{
    public override string Name { get; set; } = "Apple"
    public override string Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can have similar code for all types inheriting from `Fruit`.

Or you just have:

```
class NewApple : Fruit
{
  public override string Name{get;set;} = "Add New Apple";
  public override string Price{get;set;}
}
```

Place that in your collection, keeping your code much the same as before.